# Detect if (current) app is deleted in iOS?

Tags: ios, notifications

Can I know if a user that have downloaded the app i have developed, deletes it? How to place a tag, or request that when the app gets deleted I get a call to my server?

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no defined notification when an application is deleted.  If you must talk to a server, suspend inactive accounts after a predefined time limit.

Answer (score 5):

If push is enabled for the app, [Apple feedback service](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3) can be queried to fetch a list of devices from which the app was deleted.

Comment: Check this, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630585/does-apns-feedback-service-no-longer-exist-as-per-new-apis


The service seems to be deprecated.