# Display a message after uninstalling iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm currently working on an iPhone application and one of the critical requirements of the application is to display a message after uninstalling the application.

If it is possible, can anybody please give a solution in Objective-C language.

Comment: sorry you can not get any notification or information about when your application is deleted , Uninstall or remove from your device.  because you can't get the operating system to tell you when it deletes an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application uses APNS (apple push notifications service), you can send a periodic push notification (a silent one) to all devices, and if you get "410 - The device token is no longer active for the topic" it means that the device is no longed registered, and the app was uninstalled (probably, the user can also disable push for the specific app).

This was previously implemented using the "Feedback service" on APNS, but it seems now its done directly when sending the push.

please also see here:

[Does APNS Feedback service no longer exist as per new APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630585/does-apns-feedback-service-no-longer-exist-as-per-new-apis)

Comment: If user uninstall the app in offline,then is this possible?

Comment: You'll probably get the notification once the user first goes online (or remains offline for long-enough time)

Comment: Thanks,i want to know that the implementation of "Feedback service".Is there any tutorial is available for that implementation.Does this implementation is done at server side or client side application.Can you explain it.